# Poincaré inequality proof using Fourier series

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be open and bounded. We aim to show that for $ u $, a real infinitely differentiable function with compact support in $\Omega$ (where $ \Omega $ is contained in $ \left(-\frac{L}{2},\frac{L}{2}\right)^n $):

$
\int_\Omega u^2 \,dx \leq \left(\frac{L}{2\pi}\right)^2 \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 \,dx
$

By using Fourier series I've shown that

$
u = \sum_{k \in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^n} \left(\frac{1}{L^n} \int_{\left[-\frac{L}{2},\frac{L}{2}\right]^n} \overline{e_k}  u \,dx\right) e_k
$

where $ e_k $ is simply the function $ x \mapsto e^{ikx} $.
Set $\hat{u_k} = \int_{\left[-\frac{L}{2},\frac{L}{2}\right]^n} \overline{e_k}  u \,dx.$
So we have $u = \sum_{k \in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^n}\hat{u_k} e_k.$

Similarly,

$
D_ju = \sum_{k \in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^n} \left(\frac{1}{L^n} \int_{\left[-\frac{L}{2},\frac{L}{2}\right]^n}(i k_j) \overline{e_k} u \,dx\right) e_k =\sum_{k \in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^n}ik_j\hat{u_k} e_k.
$

So we get by using the orthonormality of $(e_k)_{k \in \frac{2\pi}{L} \mathbb{Z}^n}$ wrt to the scalar product $(u,v) \mapsto \frac{1}{L^n}\int_{\left[-\frac{L}{2},\frac{L}{2}\right]^n}\overline{u}v$ the following:

$$\int_\Omega u^2 \,dx  = \sum_{k \in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^n}|\hat{u_k}|^2$$
and
$$\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 \,dx = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k \in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^n}k_j^2|\hat{u_k}|^2 = \sum_{k \in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^n} |k|^2|\hat{u_k}|^2$$

How to finish this? Thanks. I'm having difficulty with the missing $|\hat{u_0}|$ term on the RHS.

Comment: You somehow need to make use of the fact that $u$ is compactly supported in $\Omega$.

Comment: @StefanLafon I thought we had done that by considering a large cube $\Omega \subset [-L/2,L/2]^n$

Comment: Hmmm, but where to you ever make use of the value of $u$ outside of $\Omega$?

Comment: @StefanLafon but $u$ has its compact support contained in $\Omega$, which in turn is contained in our said cube, there's nothing outside..

Comment: Exactly, and I don't think you've made use of that fact. You have merely expanded $u$ and its derivatives as Fourier series on a cube containing $\Omega$. But you haven't translated the fact that $u$ vanishes outside $\Omega$.

Comment: @StefanLafon I see what you're talking about, how do we translate this? I tried to find the estimate of $\hat{u_0} = \frac{1}{L^n}\int_{[-\frac{L}{2}, \frac{L}{2}]}u \,dx$ but to no avail, could you probably give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

I'll set $L=1$ without loss of generality without rescaling. Also, by a trivial translation, I'll rather use the cube: $(0,1)^n$. Since your function cancels at the boundary of the cube, it's better to use the orthonormal basis functions for $k\in(\mathbb N^*)^n$:
$$
e_k = \prod_{i=1}^n\sqrt2\sin(\pi k_i x_i/L)
$$
Decomposing:
$$
u = \sum_{k\in(\mathbb N^*)^n} u_ke_k
$$
You have:
$$
||u||_2^2 = \sum_{k\in(\mathbb N^*)^n} |u_k|^2 \\
||\nabla u||_2^2 = \sum_{k\in(\mathbb N^*)^n} \pi^2 |k|^2|u_k|^2 \\
$$
because for any $j=1 ...n$:
$$
e_k^j = \sqrt2\cos(\pi k_j x_j/L)\prod_{i=1, i\neq j}^n\sqrt2\sin(\pi k_i x_i/L)
$$
are still orthonormal. Using $|k|^2\geq n$, you get:
$$
||u||^2_2\leq \frac{1}{n \pi^2}||\nabla u||_2^2
$$
which is not worse than your bound for $n\geq 4$. Actually, your bound is false for $n<4$, since my bound is optimal, being reached at $u=e_{1,...,1}$.

Intuitively, the prefactor is just the (inverse of) lowest eigenvalue of the Laplacian, and is reached when $u$ is the corresponding eigenvector.

If you really want to use your basis, then you should rather instead double the domain $(-1,1)^n$ by antisymmetry:
$$
u(x_1,...,x_i,...x_n) = -u(x_1,...,-x_i,...x_n)
$$
The antisymmetrization is where you use the assumption that the trace is zero. You then use Fourier series on this domain. The coefficients are odd, so the zero mode cancels and your estimation works. This is strictly equivalent to the first method.

Hope this helps.